# Rest Assured - Json Extract

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am receiving response in the following structure:

```
[{
    "builds": [{
            "description": "JP MORGAN",
            "land": "FU",
            "companyCode": "1234",
            "accountNumber": "00000000000",
            "shortID4": "XYS"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Whenever I want to extract JSON property, e.g. description, the final object is not as I expect. It creates List having ArrayString.

```
List<String> values = resp.path("builds.description");
```

Whenever I want to test/print it is not simply possible because of the structure.
[image]

How to get the value from this JSON object to simple List which would be containing the values? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below one of the solutions can fix your problem. I recommend you to use first one.

```
String responseJson= "[{     \"builds\": [{             \"description\": \"JP MORGAN\",         },      {             \"description\": \"JP MORGAN\",         }     ] }]";
JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(responseJson);
List<String> singleDestList = jp.getList("builds[0].description");
System.out.println(singleDestList);
```

OR

```
List<List<List<String>>> descriptionsList =jp.get("builds.description");
List<Object> flatList = descriptionsList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());       
System.out.println(flatList.toString());
```

OR

```
String[] descriptionArray = jp.get("builds.description").toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", "").split(",");
List<String> descriptionList = Arrays.asList(descriptionArray);
System.out.println(descriptionList);
```